# Form input onfocus problem

Tags: jquery, html, mask, onfocus

I want to use jQuery Masked Input Plugin (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) in my registration form. My form looks like that

...

```
<input  class="part1" type="text" name="lname"  value="Last Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Last name') {this.style.color='#aea592';this.style.fontStyle='normal'; this.value=''};" onblur="if(this.value=='')  {this.style.color='#aea592'; this.style.fontStyle='italic'; this.value='Last name'}"  />
<input class="part2" type="text" id="dob" name="dob"  value="Date of Birth" onfocus="if(this.value=='Date of Birth') {this.style.color='#aea592';this.style.fontStyle='normal'; this.value=''};" onblur="if(this.value=='')  {this.style.color='#aea592'; this.style.fontStyle='italic'; this.value='Date of Birth'}" />
```

...

a the end of the file

```
<script src="core/code/js/mask.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#dob').mask('99.99.9999', {placeholder:' '});
});
</script>
```

When you open the page, Last Name field shows word "Last name" but date of birth doesn't show anything. http://prntscr.com/2miaa How can i activate mask plugin for only onfocus event?

Comment: You really shouldn't have inline javascript throughout your HTML, especially not that much.

Comment: You should read about [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://javascript.about.com/library/blunobtrusive.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yarr... Ok, first don't put so much script inside your markup. It's difficult to read, and it's going to be even more difficult to maintain. Lets try separating the style and functionality of your form first.

*Edit: A working example of this can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/ninjascript/RuFHK/2/*

#### CSS

```
input { color: #aea592; }
input.default { font-style: italic; }
```

#### HTML

```
<input class="part1 default" type="text" name="lname" value="Last Name"/>
<input class="part2 default" type="text" id="dob" name="dob" value="Date of Birth"/>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('input').bind('focus', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.hasClass('default')) {
        el.removeClass('default').val('');
    }
});
```

*phew*... OK that's a bit easier to understand. Now you want just *one more thing* to happen on focus, and that's to apply a mask to the value contained in the #dob element. Here's the edited block:

```
$('input').bind('focus', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.hasClass('default')) {
        el.removeClass('default').val('');
    }
    if (el.attr('id') === 'dob') {
        $(this).mask('99.99.9999', {placeholder:' '});
    }
});
```

Now your input should *only* be masked after it gains focus.

If you want to make sure that *some* value is returned on submit, you can always validate the content on 'blur'. I don't really feel like writing *if* statements for every field in this form, so I'm just going to map each field name and it's default value and refer to that:

```
var defaultValues = {
    'lname': 'Last Name',
    'dob': 'Date of Birth'
};
```

Now I can just refer to that map whenever I need to repopulate the field with my default values. In the case of the DOB field, it looks like the input mask plugin also has an 'unmask' option. Unfortunately because the characters within the *mask* are part of the #dob field's value, we can't just check for an empty value. Instead I'm going to use a regular expression that checks for a value that consists of nothing but whitespace and '.' chars:

```
$('input').bind('blur', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var name = el.attr('name');

    // Really we only want to do anything if the field is *empty*
    if (el.val().match(/^[\s\.]*$/)) {

        // To get our default style back, we'll re-add the classname
        el.addClass('default');

        // Unmask the 'dob' field
        if (name === 'dob') {
            el.unmask();
        }

        // And finally repopulate the field with its default value
        el.val(defaultValues[name]);
    }
});
```

Comment: thx for fast reply. But how can i return back the default value if nothing written (i mean if field empty)?

Comment: I just updated my answer -- this should get you pretty close to what you're looking to do.

Comment: Aaand I just updated my answer again because really you don't want to be using jQuery.one() at all if you're going to be validating input on every 'blur' event ^_^

Comment: please look at twitter signup form, http://twitter.com/?ref=joinus  i wanna get something like that. tery to write something. Then remove all written. The default value will be returned. But in my case i'must write the last piece of code for all fields?

Comment: Ok, I can't let things go. Call it a personal problem. I've put together a jsFiddle project for you that works and should do everything you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ninjascript/RuFHK/

Comment: I mapped all default values. The last update doesn't work for me. All values are stucked. Doesn't disappear. How to fix it?

Comment: You're right! I left an erroneous console.log statement in there. Check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ninjascript/RuFHK/2/

Comment: How to check If user doesn't change default values of the fields? if they doesn't change the script must alert about it. How can i do it?